# JQuery Menu Item click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net generated html code. I want execute jQuery click function when user click on `<a class="ctl00_Menu1_1 ctl00_Menu1_6" href="..">Download</a></td>` hyper link.I have div id `ctl00_Menu1n2Items`  for recognize the  and .

How to generate event for 2nd hyper link?

```
<div id="ctl00_Menu1n2Items" class="ctl00_Menu1_0 adjustedZIndex ctl00_Menu1_8">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr id="ctl00_Menu1n13">
        <td>
        <table class="ctl00_Menu1_7" >
            <tr>
                <td><a class="ctl00_Menu1_1 ctl00_Menu1_6" href="..">TAR Report</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr id="ctl00_Menu1n16">
        <td>
        <table class="ctl00_Menu1_7" >
            <tr>
                <td ><a class="ctl00_Menu1_1 ctl00_Menu1_6" href="..">Download</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: @DG3 I am trying to execute JQuery function when user clicks on  <a class="ctl00_Menu1_1 ctl00_Menu1_6" href="..">Download</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ctl00_Menu1n16 a").click(function(){alert("Clicked me");})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("a", "#ctl00_Menu1n2Items")[1].click(function(e){})
```

Answer (score -1):

The TR for each menu item has a unique ID. You can leverage that ID.

```
$("#ctl00_Menu1n16 a.ctl00_Menu1_1").click(...);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {   
          $("#ctl00_Menu1n16 a.ctl00_Menu1_1 ctl00_Menu1_6").click(function() {
            alert("Hi");

Comment: Woops, copy/pasted too many CSS classes. I've updated the example.